# Module '"project/node_modules/@angular/common/index"' has no exported member 'ControlGroup'

Tags: angular

I am importing ControlGroup in my project like this

```
import { ControlGroup } from '@angular/common';
```

which was working fine until i upgraded my project to angular2.1

Is there any other way of doing the same in angular2.1?

Comment: there is no such ControlGroup package int @angular/common, are looking for Form Control Group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything related to forms is now in `@angular/forms`. Also the names of the models have changed. If you are using model forms, you would do something like

```
import {FormGroup, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
      <form [formGroup]="form">
        <input name="first" formControlName="first" [(ngModel)]="example.first"/>
        <input name="last" formControlName="last" [(ngModel)]="example.last"/>
      </form>
  `,
})
export class App {
  form: FormGroup;
  example = { first: '', last: '' };

  constructor(builder: FormBuilder) {
    this.form = builder.group({
      first: '',
      last: ''
    })
  }
}
```

Then you need to import the `ReactiveFormsModule` into your module

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  imports: [ ReactiveFormsModule ]
})
class AppModule {}
```

#### [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/YSLDbWtJlZX5It1qGRq2?p=preview)

**See Also:**

- [Cookbook: Dynamic Forms](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/dynamic-form.html)
- [Docs: Forms (declarative forms)](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/forms.html)

Comment: i looked for it, it has been deprecated now.. will use FormGroup, thanks